# Connecting a UDP Server to a Client in JAVA

Tags: java

I have a server and a client(say client1) both on a single file working perfectly. I have a situation like: I have another client(say client2) which sends information to the server. This server has to send the information taken from client2 to client1. But when I used same port number and same IP Address on both the server and client1 when I try to send information from client2, the client1 is also accepting at a time.

How can I send the information from client2 so that first server first accepts it and then sends that information to client1?

### **Client2 Code:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class Client1
{

    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {

        try {
                InetAddress ip=InetAddress.getByName("228.5.6.7");
            int port=4270;

            MulticastSocket sock=new MulticastSocket();
            String msg="Hello All";

            DatagramPacket packet;
           while(true)
          {
            packet =new DatagramPacket(msg.getBytes(),msg.length(),ip,port);
            sock.send(packet);
           }

      } 
     catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }

}
```

### **My Server and Client Code:**

```
class Server implements Runnable
{

    public void run()
    {
        try
        {       
            //get the multicast ip
            InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("228.5.6.7");

            int port=4270;
             byte[] buffer=new byte[100];
             byte[] data = null; 

            MulticastSocket sock=new MulticastSocket(port);

            //join the multicast group
            sock.joinGroup(ip);
            while(true)
            {
                //create a datagram packet in which u will receive the msg  

                Thread.sleep(2000);  
                DatagramPacket pack=new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length);
                sock.receive(pack);
                String msg = new String(buffer);              
                System.out.println("Sever Has Received :" +msg);

               //SENDING THE MESSAGE TO CLIENT
               System.out.println("Sending the Message!!!");


               data = msg.getBytes(); 
               DatagramPacket pack1 = new DatagramPacket(data,msg.length(),ip,port);
               Thread.sleep(2000); 
               sock.send(pack1);
            }

        }
         catch (Exception ex) {
         Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
         t.getUncaughtExceptionHandler().uncaughtException(t, ex);
         }

    }
  }
```

## ***Client1 Code:***

```
class Client implements Runnable
{

    public void run()
    {

       try {
       InetAddress address1 = InetAddress.getByName("228.5.6.7");
       int port=4271;
       MulticastSocket socket1 = new MulticastSocket(port);
      //join a Multicast group and send the group salutations
       socket1.joinGroup(address1);
       byte[] data1 = new byte[256];
       DatagramPacket packet1 = new DatagramPacket(data1,data1.length);
       while(true)
      {                                
       // receive the packets 
       socket1.receive(packet1); 
       String str = new String(packet1.getData(),0,packet1.getLength());
       Thread.sleep(2000);
       System.out.println("Client Received : "+str);
      }  
    }
      catch (Exception ex) {
      Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
      t.getUncaughtExceptionHandler().uncaughtException(t, ex);
     }
   }    
 }
```

### **MAIN PROGRAM**

```
class ClientAndServer
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      Server s = new Server();

     //First start Server and then Start client
     Thread t1 = new Thread(s);
      t1.start();
      Client c = new Client();
     Thread t2 = new Thread(c);

        t2.start();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a `MulticastSocket` to link `Client1` <-> `Server` <-> `Client2`. If Server send a message, EVERY client will received it, this is from the  [MulticastSocket doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/MulticastSocket.html)

> When one sends a message to a multicast group, all subscribing recipients to that host and port receive the message

If you don't want that, you might need to use two distinct socket, using two port

- port 1 : `Client1` <-> `Server`
- port 2 : `Client2` <-> `Server`

And you can then redirect the message only to one or the other port but will have two distinct channel of message